# With a RNN, how can we predict a currency price to reach a specific price in a given time period?

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, bitcoin

I am working on a bitcoin price predictor, and I realize that it's non sense to predict an exact price at a given time.
What we want when predicting some currency price can be summarize with this question: **"What is the probability for the price to reach value X in a specific time range ?"**

I have hard time to integrate this thinking into a RNN /LSTM architecture. My first thought was to build a **custom Loss function** that compare the output of the RNN (typically, a predicted price) with the real lower and upper price of the next day, then if the **lower_price < predicted_value < upper_price**  the RNN output should be "classified" as correct (loss = 0), otherwise the loss would be > 0. But I am sure there already exists a better solution for this kind of problem.

Any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of different ways to do what you are asking. However I think what you are looking for is a [quantile loss function](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-quantile-regression-c85481548b5a).

```
def tilted_loss(q,y,f):
    e = (y-f)
    return K.mean(K.maximum(q*e, (q-1)*e), axis=-1)
```

[Notebook with full source code](https://github.com/sachinruk/KerasQuantileModel/blob/master/Keras%20Quantile%20Model.ipynb). Or if you prefer PyTorch you can find an [implementation here](https://github.com/AIStream-Peelout/flow-forecast/blob/7343cfbc6685e4b8748c3494fbb66da0de9aa99a/flood_forecast/custom/custom_opt.py#L159).

Comment: So, how would I use the network to show the range in which 90% of the futur (next day say) price will fall in (for instance) ? Thanks